# Using paramiko library to read and process a remote TEXT file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to read a remote TEXT file in a server and process it by each line splitting it with " "(Space) and to find the lines where the word "Stock:"is there and take those lines and the split values and process them and insert the data to another remote database.

have done it locally and is working fine , a part of the script is shown below.

So when i googled and research found i can use paramiko library to access the remote file, but i'm not sure how to use it in the context of my need.

i have pasted the code below for your suggestions,Kindly let me know what all changes i have to do in the below code.

Any suggestions will be of great help.

```
import psycopg2
import time
import os
import MySQLdb
import paramiko
from utils.config import Configuration as Config
from utils.postgres_helper import get_connection
from utils.utils import get_global_config

start_time = time.perf_counter()

#Magento connection 
try:
    source_host = 'magento'
    conf = get_global_config()

    host=conf.get(source_host, 'host')
    user=conf.get(source_host, 'user')
    passwd=conf.get(source_host, 'password')
    port=int(conf.get(source_host, 'port'))
    db=conf.get(source_host, 'db'))

except mysql.connector.Error as e:
   print ("MYSQL: Unable to connect!", e.msg)
   sys.exit(1)

# Postgresql connection
 try:
   cnx_psql = get_connection(get_global_config(), 'pg_dwh')
   print ("DWH Connected")
 except psycopg2.Error as e:
   print('PSQL: Unable to connect!\n{0}').format(e)
   sys.exit(1)


# Cursors initializations
 cur_psql = cnx_psql.cursor()

try:

    #filePath='''/Users/linu/Downloads/log''' 
    filePath='''/Aio2/log/stockitem/log.txt''' 
    table='staging.stock_dump'

    SQL="""DROP TABLE IF EXISTS """+  table + """;CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS """+ table + """
      (created_date TEXT, product_sku TEXT, previous_stock TEXT, current_stock TEXT );"""

    cur_psql.execute(SQL)
    cnx_psql.commit()


   ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
   ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

   try:
        ssh.connect(host, username=user, password=passwd)
   except paramiko.SSHException:
        print "Connection Failed"
        quit()
   try:     
     sftp_client = ssh_client.open_sftp()
     remote_file = sftp_client.open(filePath)

     ftp = ssh.open_sftp()
     file=ftp.file(filePath, "r", -1)
     data=file.read()
     fields = string.split(data)  # How i can split it by space.
     for i in fields:
        if string.find(i, 'Stock:')>-1:
            print i



         #for line in remote_file:
           #if 'Stock:' in line:
            #fields=line.split(" ")
            #date_part1=fields[0]
            #date_part2=fields[1][:-1]
            #sku=fields[3]
            #prev_stock=fields[5]
            #current_stock=fields[7]
            #if prev_stock.strip()==current_stock.strip():
                #continue
            #else:
               #cur_psql.execute("insert into " + table+"(created_date, product_sku, previous_stock , current_stock)" + " select CAST('" + date_part1+ " "+ date_part2 + "' AS TEXT)" +", CAST('"+sku+"' AS TEXT),CAST('" + prev_stock +"' AS TEXT),CAST('" +current_stock  + "' AS TEXT);")
    finally:
    remote_file.close()
    client.close()

    cnx_psql.commit()       
    cur_psql.close()
    cnx_psql.close()
    print("Data loaded to DWH from text file")
    print("Data porting took %s seconds to finish---" % (time.perf_counter() - start_time))

except (Exception, psycopg2.Error) as error:
        print ("Error while fetching data from PostgreSQL", error)
        print("Error adding  information.")
        quit()
```